# D3 Javascript: Removing and updating elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have just a simple list of numbers, that is using the setInteval() function with a call to update(). Instead of removing the numbers after each call it just appends it on. I tried using d3.select("g").remove(), but that didn't work either. Can someone explain this, and better explain the enter() and exit() methods because I am having a hard time wrapping my head around these calls.

```
var svg = d3.select("#first").append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height", 500);

function update(data) {

  var text = svg.select("g")
  .data(data);

  text.enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
  text.exit().remove();
}



setInterval(function() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    data[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  console.log(data);
  update(data);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the lack of a separate "enter" and "update" selections (besides that, you are not appending texts correctly to the SVG, so I changed your code a little bit).

Here you bind the data:

```
var text = svg.selectAll(".myText")
    .data(data);
```

And this is your "exit" selection (as you `data.length` is always the same, you don't even need this selection):

```
text.exit()
    .remove();
```

Now comes the change. This is your enter selection (again, as you `data.length` is always 5, "enter" only works the first time you call the function):

```
text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "myText")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){ return 20 + i*16})
    .attr("y", 20);
```

And this is your update selection:

```
text.text(function(d) {
    return d;
 });
```

Here is the working code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",200)
  .attr("height", 100);

function update(data) {

  var text = svg.selectAll(".myText")
  .data(data);
 
 text.exit().remove();

  text.enter()
  .append("text")
 .attr("class", "myText")
 .attr("x", function(d,i){ return 20 + i*16})
 .attr("y", 20);
 
 text.text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
  
}



setInterval(function() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    data[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  }
  update(data);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I'm using D3 v3 here.